# Is it safe to keep a plasma lighter in my bag?

Tags: technology, storage, safety, hardware

So I have a bag where I store my laptop, headphones, swiss army knife and cables on the go, or just hang it around my door handle if I’m home and need something. I recently got a plasma lighter stick with safety lock (requires press + slide motion to expose the points and turn them on). I was wondering if it’s safe to store this in my bag

Comment: Asking if something works is not a Lifehack.  You should state a problem and request a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I'd put that in a **small, rigid container** that you can close, just to be sure.

Especially if you sometimes carry more things in there, there's always a small chance of both the slider getting pushed sideways and the button being pressed simultaneously. And even though the **chance** this happens is small, the **consequence** would be setting the bag with your laptop on fire and losing it.

[image]

You could find something like this, these come in various sizes. If you can't find a perfect match and lighter ends up rattling around inside, you could always add some padding (for example a few bits of silicone cut to size, inserted to sit at the bottom and in the lid).